# Steam needs to install addition packages libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 and glx:i386

Tags: package-management, games, steam

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, I just downloaded steam and I'm getting

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
[sudo] password for usernamehere:
```

Once I put in my password I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
Press return to continue:
```

I press enter and it closes and opens up steam but it asks me this every.single.time.

Is there any way to fix/bypass this nuisance?

Any help is appreciated thank you for your time.

Comment: I did not see that thread before and...I think the first comment actually solved my issue. Thank you for finding it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to nephente for finding the answer and the person in that thread he linked to for answering it. Solution was the following code

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386
```